# Code after if block inside a for loop doesn't work

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, return

I'm new to java. This is a question about if block in a for loop. This code is from a algorithm practice.
The code is to take an int array but treat it as an integer and add one to this integer, and convert the new integer back to array format. if I didn't describe it clearly, please refer to the original [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/plus-one/discuss/).

```
    public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {

    int size = digits.length;
    for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(digits[i] < 9) {
            System.out.println("tag1 digits.i = " + digits[i]);
            digits[i]++;
            System.out.println("tag2 digits.i = " + digits[i]);
            return digits; // <-- return
        }

        System.out.println("tag3 digits.i= " + digits[i]);
        digits[i] = 0; //?
        System.out.println("tag4 digits.i= " + digits[i]);
    }

    int[] intOut = new int [size+1];
    intOut[0] = 1;
    return intOut;
}
```

In the codes above, I added some println() to show how `digit[i]` changes.

When the input is `{1,2,3}`, why the line of `digits[i] = 0` doesnt work? Reading the code I thought all int in `int[] digits` will be set to 0.

If it `return` in the if block, **does it mean stop the current iteration and ignore the rest code in the for loop after the if block?**

**update** I failed to describe it clearly.My question was not on what and how to accomplish with the code, but about given the input i mentioned, why the code after if statement doesn't work. And now i learnt that the return statement at the last line of the if block means to do it(stop current iteration). Sorry for this silly question..!

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: You'll never get to `digits[i] = 0;` because you return if `digits[i] < 9`.

Comment: Your digits array does not have a value greater than 9, try the array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14}

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper Won't make a difference; it returns on the first element.

Comment: *If it return in the if block, does it mean stop the current iteration and ignore the rest code in the for loop after the if block?* Yes, `return` exits the method. What did you think it does?

Comment: Didn't even see the return statement. @Robin, you need to explicitly state what you are trying to accomplish with this code snippet.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper I meant the last line of the if statement.

Comment: @shmosel just learnt it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm honestly curious what you thought it meant.

Comment: didnt have any idea. too new to know it

Comment: @Robin: *"didnt have any idea"* is the most important lesson for you in this whole question.  When your code misbehaves, you fo over it with a fine-tooth comb, and you try to convince yourself that you know exacty what every word does. If you realize that you "didnt have any idea" what sometihng in the code does, you have found your treasure. You stop, research and find out exactly what it does. This will teach you better than any teacher, and certainly better than SO.

Comment: Don't worry about down votes... Some users in SO think that they know everything and they does not allow to ask some basic question from beginners............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code add one to the number passed as digit array.

So when you add 1 to 123, you get 124. The code starts with the last digit, looks whether it is less than 9, then add 1 only to the last digit.
**this happens in the if-block. The return ends the function**

The code which sets a digit to 0 will only reached when there is some overflow. This overflow can only happen when you pass a number where the last digit is 9.

To reach this case you must pass something like 129 (or {1,2,9}). Then the last digit become 0 and the second last digit is checked. In this case added by one, return 130

To reach the code behind the loop, you have to pass a list where all digits are set to 9. For example 99 (or {9,9}).

In this case, the last digit will set to 0, the first digit will set to 0, then a new list will be generates with one more digit. Initially all digits are set to 0. Then the first digit will be set to 1. This results in 100.

`return` leaves the function/method
`break` leaves the surrounding loop (for,while)

So the answer to your question in bold is **YES**

Answer (score 0):

For the below loop:

```
for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(digits[i] < 9) {
        System.out.println("tag1 digits.i = " + digits[i]);
        digits[i]++;
        System.out.println("tag2 digits.i = " + digits[i]);
        return digits;
    }

    System.out.println("tag3 digits.i= " + digits[i]);
    digits[i] = 0; //?
    System.out.println("tag4 digits.i= " + digits[i]);
}
```

The moment `digit[i] < 9` it will go inside the `if` condition. But after that it will return the `digit[]` and will come out of the method.

Hence you will never see `digit[i] < 9` i.e. **1 to 8** being set to 0.

Comment: It is not 1 to 8, it is 0 to 8 which are never set to 0, or more simpler only 9 will cause overflow and this means set to 0, and going to the previous digit

Comment: yes, but a 0 will be incremented as any digit != 9.